# $ x^x\ln x $ and $ x^2 \ln x $

Tags: logarithms

Suppose we have an expression like $ \ln x^{x^{x}} $. We can write it as $ \ln x^{x^{x}} = x^x\ln x $. But this can also be written as:
$$
\ln x^{x^{x}} = \ln t^x; \ where \ t = x^x, \\ \implies \ln t^x = x\ln t = x \ln x^x = x.x \ln x = x^2 \ln x
$$
I know I am wrong somewhere in my logic but where?

Comment: You took the order of exponentiation wrongly. For example, $3^{3^3}$ should be computed as $3^{27}$, not $(3^3)^3= 27^3 = 3^9$. So $$\mathrm{ln} x^{x^x} = x^x \mathrm{ln}x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiation is not associative:
$$
x^{(x^x)} \not= (x^x)^x = x^{x\cdot x} = x^{x^2}.
$$

This is why after taking logarithms you get different values.

Answer (score 1):

Your error strarts from here:

$$x^{x^x}=x^{(x^x)}≠\left(x^x\right)^x=x^{x^2}=x^{(x^2)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

When you write $\ln x^{x^x} = x^x \ln x$, you read $x^{x^x}$ as $x^{(x^x)}$. When you get $x^2 \ln x$, you have read $x^{x^x}$ as $(x^x)^x$. The first one is correct.